# How to find bullets or numbered bullets is present in NSString using NSRegularExpressionSearch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, bullet-span

I have a `NSString` which may have `ordered bullets` or `unordered bullets` as a string. I want to remove that bullets alone from the string.

Can someone please help me out in this?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim bullets using below code. I am not using Regular Expression. I am giving idea how to identify and remove bullets..

```
NSString *bulletString = @"\u2022";
self.lbl.text=[strWithBullets stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:bulletString withString:@""];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this. It is only removing unordered bullets. I want both ordered and unordered bullets to be removed.

Comment: Try with different bullet codes as shown in this link..http://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/mailman/message/9699987/
U can find other codes for bullets from this link...!

Comment: You can print the output using NSLog and find the uni code for Ordered List bullet and use that code to trim..from your strings...!